# Is it necessary to add mobileprovision file on ipad to test the ipa file

Tags: ios, ipad

I have ipad app i have made ipa file of that and sent to client for testing it does not install on ipad i have just sent him the ipad file only should i also send the mobileprovison file with that ipa file for testing it on ipad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your client will need to install the Mobile Provision file as well. Also make sure that your client's iPad's device identifier is actually included in the provisioning profile you are using.

In the company I work for, we rely on [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/) to handle all of those technical details for us instead of manually sending builds and profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to send the Mobile Provision file too. Check under ["How Can the Beta Testers Install the App?" section here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1669/how-to-host-a-beta-test-for-your-ios-app)